# Pagination comments

Tags: comments, pagination

For some odd reason, I can't seem to make the pagination work for comments.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'products',
    'status'        => 'approve',
);

// The Query
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

// Comment Loop
if ( $comments ) {
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
        echo '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No comments found.';
}
```

I also tried to use `wp_list_comments` and then `paginate_comments_links();` but the pagination is still not visible even though there's plenty of comments it should show.

What else should I add so that the pagination works? I do know I should use the `offset` and `number` parameter. But don't know how.
Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: Not sure if it helps, but the comments aren't being displayed on a post or post_type. I'm placing the comments on a seperated page.

Comment: How do you define offset and number

Comment: I don't actually, I already added it inside the example because I know I've to use those two parameters. `The WP_Comment_Query` doesn't have a `$paged` parameter yet, like we see with posts.

Comment: In order to page comments, you need to pass something to `number` (*the amount of comments per page*) and something to `offset`. The offset will depend on the current page and the value passed to `number`.

Comment: I know, that's why I already added `number/offset`, but I don't know what to do next. I need some sort of an example.

Comment: Then you should update your post because according to me, and maybe all others that have read your post, you are setting `number` and `offset` to a predefined variable that you did not include. That is why I asked you in the first place. So at this stage, `number` and `offset` is set to nothing, and you do not know how to set them

Comment: Updated post. :)

Comment: Did you checked if `Break comments into pages with X top level...` is checked in Settings -> Discussion,  because I don't see any adequate reason paginate_comments_link() would fail..

Comment: Yes, it's checked. Also, `Break comments into pages with 10 top level comments per page` and I change 10 to 2, two comments are shown on the page. I don't understand either why the pagination doesn't show.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried [paginate_comments_links();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/paginate_comments_links)?

```
<div class="navigation">
  <?php paginate_comments_links(); ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have. I also tried `the_comments_navigation() ` and `get_the_comments_pagination()` I don't really understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: It would help if you actually read the question *I also tried to use wp_list_comments and then paginate_comments_links()*. Rather post a comment and ask for clarity